# NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification useless?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using Core Data for a while now with a background contex, and was wondering why everyone advise to use the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` for merging from the background to the main context. I created a Test-Project with one `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, a main context and a background context. Here is the code fragment for initalisation:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}

return _managedObjectContext;
}



- (NSManagedObjectContext *)backgroundContext {
if (_backgroundContext != nil) {
    return _backgroundContext;
}
_backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
_backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

return _backgroundContext;
}
```

until now, i would have listened to the save notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:self.backgroundContext];
```

But i realised, it doesn't matter if I merge from that notification. I can edit and save either context, and the other one get's merged after some seconds itself.

So. my question, why would i even need the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`?

Comment: [core data concurrency](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131)

Comment: It may look like it's working without handling the notification and doing a merge, but it's really just luck.  What the notification does is allow the other context, into which you will merge, to know about the changes.  This matters because contexts cache stuff.

Comment: In all my tests, ist merged for itself. But if i have to merge using that notification, why do all samples just merge from the background to the main context? Don't I have then to merge the other way around when saving the main context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your contexts are not related.  They are both root contexts attached to the same persistent store coordinator.

A change to the persistent store is automatically pushed to the root contexts associated with it (which is why you don't need to handle the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification.)

`NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` is useful when dealing with more complex context ancestry, since a mid-level context does not automatically notify all of its children when changed.

As an example, check out the architecture diagram for Cadmium (https://github.com/jmfieldman/Cadmium).  When a background child context saves up to the writer context, the main context must handle a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` on the main thread to incorporate the updates.

Comment: If this is correct, why is the shared persistent store coordinator design using NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification to manually merge changes between the main and private contexts? "Saving any one of these managed object contexts will push changes through the shared coordinator and on to the backing store file. While the changes from each context are available in the store after a save, no context is aware of the changes made in any other context." https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/introducing-the-big-nerd-ranch-core-data-stack/